# How to do more than 1 action with onClick handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button with action from props:

```
<div className={classes['Menu__nav-item']}
     onClick={props.InformationScroll}
>
    Info
</div>
```

but I want to execute one more action, how to properly do it ?

```
  <div className={classes['Menu__nav-item']}
         onClick={props.InformationScroll; () => setFlag(!flag)} #pseudocode
    >
        Info
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a function in your component which performs both actions:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const [flag,setFlag] = useState(false);
    
    const infoClicked = (event) => { 
        props.informationScroll(event); // forward the MouseEvent
        setFlag(!flag);
    }
    
    return (
        <div 
          className={classes['Menu__nav-item']}
          onClick={infoClicked}>
          Info
        </div>
    );

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to forward the event parameter, `informationScroll` might be using it.

Comment: You're right, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className={classes['Menu__nav-item']}
         onClick={() => {
props.InformationScroll()
setFlag(!flag)
}} #pseudocode
    >
        Info
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write a separate function and send the relevant parameters with "onClick".

Comment: Adding code would make your answer much more helpful to both the OP and future visitors :)